# core data relationship, how to insert and retrieve data from relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am new in IOS development and I am having a problem when using core data specially when using relationships

I have the following relationship
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wny8T.png)

as you see i have tree entities and what i am trying to do is insert into CredentialsFood entity the data when food is consumed by a particular user

so I am trying to insert using the following code

```
    // adding to credetialsFood Entity
NSManagedObjectContext *context1 = [appD managedObjectContext];
CredentialsFood *credentialsFood = (CredentialsFood *)        [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CredentialsFood"   inManagedObjectContext:context1];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
credentialsFood.toFood.food_id = item_id;
credentialsFood.toCred.email = @"123";
credentialsFood.date = currentDate;


// here's where the actual save happens,
if(![context1 save:&errorCoreData]){
    NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Food date Saved");
}
```

the code works fine 
however when retrieving I try for example get all CredentialsFood.date where Credentials.email = 123
I receive nothing

I don't really know What i am doing wrong this is the code to retrieve

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context2 = [appD managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *foodEntity =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Credentials" inManagedObjectContext:context2];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSError *error2 = nil;
NSString * userid =@"123";

NSPredicate *foodPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email contains[cd] %@)",userid];

[request setEntity:foodEntity];
[request setPredicate:foodPredicate];

NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error2];


if([objects count]== 0){
    NSLog (@"no matches found");

}
else {
    //NSLog(@"aasdasdad %@", objects);
    matches = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"bb %@",[matches valueForKey:@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"bb %@",[matches valueForKey:@"email"]);
    NSLog(@"bb %@",[matches valueForKey:@"password"]);
    //NSLog(@"hhhhhhhhhhhhhh %@",[matches valueForKey:@"credentails"]);

    NSMutableSet *query = [matches mutableSetValueForKey:@"credentails"];


    NSArray *financialData =[matches valueForKeyPath:@"credentails"];
    NSLog(@"%@",financialData);
    NSLog(@"%@",[financialData valueForKey:@"date"]);
```

the data is inside core data however i don't know if it is performing the relation, the Food entity is populated and the CredentialsFood is also populated

I also getting the warnings 
abstract entity Food has no children
abstract entity Credentials has no children
abstract entity CredentialsFood has no children

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you first create the object:

```
CredentialsFood *credentialsFood = (CredentialsFood *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CredentialsFood" inManagedObjectContext:context1];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
credentialsFood.toFood.food_id = item_id;
credentialsFood.toCred.email = @"123";
```

...you do not appear to be assigning anything to the `toFood` or `toCred` relationships. Related objects are not created automatically, so those properties will be nil. In Objective-C it's not an error to run this code while those properties are nil, but the code has no effect. It looks like you need to create (or fetch) an instance of `Food` and of `Credentials`, and assign those new objects to the `toFood` and `toCred` attributes.